# load the urls of my external images with the https protocol in nextjs

Tags: next.js, nextjs-image

Hello I am new to nextjs .The image urls of my external images are loaded with the http protocol, however I would like it to be loaded with the https protocol.
how to do it.
?

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe setting the protocol to `https` in the config will do the job. https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/optimizing/images#remote-images